# The definition of integrals over sets which are not rectangles. ("Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, definition

In "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak, the author defined integrals over sets which are not rectangles as follows.

> We have thus far dealt with the integrals of functions over rectangles. Integrals over other sets are easily reduced to this type. If $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then **characteristic function** $\chi_
> C$ of $C$ is defined by $$\chi_C(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0 & x\notin C, \\
> 1 & x\in C.
> \end{cases}$$ If $C\subset A$ for some closed rectangle $A$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then $\int_C f$ is defined as $\int_A f\cdot\chi_C$, provided $f\cdot\chi_C$ is integrable. This certainly occurs (Problem 3-14) if $f$ and $\chi_C$ are integrable.

If we are given $f:C\to\mathbb{R}$, first of all, we need to extend $f$ to a function $g$ which is defined on $A$ to define $\int_C f$.
Since $\int_C f=\int_A g\cdot\chi_C$, the values of $g$ on $A-C$ is not important at all.

I wonder why the author didn't define $\int_C f$ like this:

Suppose $f:C\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.
If $C\subset A$ for some closed rectangle $A$, we define $g:A\to\mathbb{R}$ as $g(x) = f(x)$ if $x\in C$ and $g(x) = 0$ if $x\in A-C$.
We define $\int_C f=\int_A g$, provided $g$ is integrable.

Comment: They are the same. Your $g$ is exactly $f\cdot\chi_C$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes. But we need to extend $f:C\to\mathbb{R}$ whenever we calculate $\int_C f$. I don't like this situation. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @佐武五郎: But, your proposed definition also involves extending $f$, no? You define $\int_C f=\int_A g$, and $g$ is an extension of $f$ to $A$.

Comment: @Joe That's certainly true. I just like my definition. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @佐武五郎: I think the way you present your definition is a little clearer than Spivak, but it is important to note that it is *trivially* equivalent to Spivak's. I'm not sure what more there is to say.